# Problem with id="wpadminbar visualization

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my wordpress site. When the site is working in onlaine regim – don’t have admin log, is visualized wpadminbar in top header. How to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your theme function.php

> add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

[More info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar)